# Trying to use scp and pscp to transfer a file!

Tags: server, ssh

I am trying to transfer a file from my local desktop to my ubuntu ip. I have tried the command scp (my file) ubuntu@172.31.95.248:/opt/siff to directly transfer it where I want to, however I either get the error

ssh: connect to host 172.31.95.248 port 22: Connection timed out
lost connection

or

FATAL ERROR: Network error: Connection timed out.

I have tried pinging my IP and it connects fine, so I am not sure why this will not connect. Thank you.

Comment: Your login is ubuntu? and the machine you are trying to transfer to has `openssh-server` installed and running?  Desktops by default only have `ssh` (the client) installed, and you provided no details as to release or versions (server, desktop etc)

Comment: I'm sorry. I am new to all of this. My login is ubuntu and I am running it off of a SSH from PuTTY if that makes sense. The version I am running is 18.0.4.3 LTS.

Comment: If you're talking about a desktop install, only the client software (`openssh-client`)  is installed by default, so you can `ssh` to other boxes, but not `ssh` into the box itself. I usually `ssh localhost` from the box itself to ensure I can access it remotely, before i try remotely.  Does the box you're trying to have `openssh-server` installed & running?  adding a `-v` to turn on verbose can often provide more useful info too (FYI it's 18.04.3; format being *year.month* being key; after that is just install or update level)